# How does one display the full date and year and time at the top right in MacBook Pro Monterey?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I've Googled this and none of the options work. I tried going to clock but it doesn't work. The options in this page: https://www.howtoisolve.com/how-to-add-date-to-the-menu-bar-on-mac-macbook-change-date-time-format/ are not the same that I see.

[image]

How do I make it appear?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", are you saying that you don't get the date in the menubar when you set the options, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In Monterey, the Clock options are still in the Dock & Menubar preference pane, but they have changed appearance.

[image]

There are no options to add the year.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of icons in menu bar, try to hide extra apps there and full date will appears (it helps me on macbook with notch)